# Batch Script to get latest folder

Tags: batch-file

I have to determine the latest release version from a release location containing release artifacts. Here is how the folder looks like:-

```
1.4
1.4.1
1.5
1.5.1
1.5.2
latest
```

In the above example my script should return 1.5.2. The release engineer creates a folder called `latest` and puts the latest release artifacts (1.5.2's contents  in the above case) inside it - so I have a easy way to copy the latest release. But my problem is I want to print the version as well. here's my attempt:-

```
@echo off

SET Remote="\\path to release location"
SET newest=""

for /f %%a in ('dir %Remote% /b /od') do (if NOT %%a=="latest" SET newest=%%a)

echo %newest%
```

This works fine with the above example. But the release engineer sometimes creates a `tmp` or some other folder there (basically he forgets to clean up) and that screws up my naive assumption of filtering out just "latest". Is there a easy way to sort the folders that start with a number declare the newest release version.

Also pls suggest if there are any better idea of solving this

Comment: Pipe the output of the dir command to FINDSTR and give it a regular expression to find just directory names with numbers. Something like this for the findstr: `findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"`

Comment: Just ask the release engineer to place a marker with the release version in the `latest` directory too!

Comment: Thanks @Squashman - Here's what I came up with: `for /f %%a in ('dir %cd% /b /od  ^| findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"') do (SET newest=%%a)`
@Compo: Thanks for your tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not rely on the newest modified date actually being the greatest release number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set newest=000000000
PUSHD \\servername\share\directory
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /ad ^| findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"') do (
    FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%H IN ("%%~G") DO (
        SET "node1=000%%H"
        SET "node1=!node1:~-3!"
        SET "node2=000%%I"
        SET "node2=!node2:~-3!"
        SET "node3=000%%J"
        SET "node3=!node3:~-3!"
        IF 1!node1!!node2!!node3! GTR 1!newest! (
            set newest=!node1!!node2!!node3!
            set newrelease=%%G
        )
    )
)
echo %newrelease%
POPD
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans - wondering where exactly will the results be different vs the  `dir /on` option

Comment: @Zakir, make three directories from the cmd prompt. Name them 1.1, 11.1 and 2.1.  Then use your DIR command.  Do you think 11.1 will be last using `DIR /ON`?

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution here as per @Squashman's suggestion:-

```
@echo off

SET Remote="//Path to release loc"
SET newest=not set

for /f %%a in ('dir %Remote% /b /on  ^| findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"') do (SET newest=%%a)

echo %newest%
```

Note:- The sort order `/od` vs `/on` is something I have to work with the release engineer to agree upon to protect against situations like: patching an older release does not over-write the latest release

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: I know this is a repeated comment but the easiest method involves the engineer, who you're collaborating with, including a file. The file could either have a known size or extension with the release as it's name or a have a known name with the release as it's single line content.

Comment: Why not break up the directory name into variables and test which one is the newest with some if statements?